# Authorization header issue with safari

Tags: javascript, ssl, safari, fetch-api, http-authentication

Safari is not sending authorization to the server on the production server. This works perfectly on Firefox, chrome and opera.

```
      fetch(url, {
     "Content-type": "application/json",
     Authorization: "Bearer sample_token"

    }).then(res => console.log(res))
    .catch(err => console.log(err));
```

Comment: Were you able to find a solution?

Comment: There's a lot of discussion about this around the web. It seems Safari is particular about the `Authorization` header. In some cases, Safari won't allow the header to be changed because the SSL cert is self-signed. In other cases, the request may have been cached. Some users report changing the name of the header from `Authorization` to something else fixes the issue, but that needs to happen both on the front and back end, and may not be the correct solution.